# django создать только одну запись модель

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите как ограничить создание записей в django. необходимо чтобы была создана только одна запись и все

```
class Setting(models.Model):
   STATUS = (
      ('True', 'Опубликовать'),
      ('False', 'Не публиковать'),
   )
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Название')
   keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Ключевые слова')
   description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Описание')
   company = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Компания')
   copyright = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='copyright')
   favicon = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Иконка сайта')
   logotip = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Логотип')
   address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Адрес')
   phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15, verbose_name='Телефон')
   workschedule = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15, verbose_name='График работы')
   email = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='Электроная почта')
   smtpserver = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='SMTPserver')
   smtpemail = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='SMTPemail')
   smtppassword = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='SMTPpassword')
   smtpport = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=8, verbose_name='SMTPport')
   privacypolicy = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Политика конфиденциальности')
   conditionofpayment = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Условия оплаты')
   usloviyadostavka = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Условия Доставка')
   garantii = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Гарантии')
   vozvrat = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Возврат')
   contact = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Контакты')
   aboutus = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='О нас')
   useragreement = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Пользовательское соглашение')
   status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS, verbose_name='Статус')
   create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано')
   update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.title

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = "Общие настроики"
      verbose_name_plural = "Общие настроики"
```

Comment: Переопределить метод has_add_permission в соответствующей админке?

Comment: А у данной модели вообще предполагается только одна запись, или одна запись на пользователя?